# How to process and excel file that is being sent from front end(website) in c# webapi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Currently I am working on a backend code in c# to process an excel file that is being sent from front end(web). I have tried to google for some samples code but did not manage to find a suitable example. What I am doing is as follow:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] string value)
    {           

        if (value == null)               
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        else
        {
           //Process the excel file               

            var response = PTWGenericResponse.CreateSuccessReponse();
            return Ok(response);
        }

    }
```

What I am unsure if string is the right data type to use or if my approach is correct. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is, First write a method to recieve the file from the API Request, and save the file to backend disk folder, then you can read the file from that folder and do your process.

Here is an example about [Uploading a File in ASP.Net Web API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/uploading-a-file-in-Asp-Net-web-api/):

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post()  
{  
    HttpResponseMessage result = null;  
    var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;  
   if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)  
    {  
        var docfiles = new List<string>();  
        foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)  
        {  
            var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];  
            var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + postedFile.FileName);  
            postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);  
            docfiles.Add(filePath);  
        }  
        result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, docfiles);  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);  
    }  
     return result;  
}
```

Comment: Hi Yu Yang, I am not so familiar with "public HttpResponseMessage Post() ", is this another way to write a Post Handler?

Comment: I find that `IActionResult` is in `asp.net core`, so you're writing `asp.net core` ?  Besides you can mark the word gray with two **`**  symbol